# Pass a JsonObject to Model SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to pass a JSON object from the list of returned results to a Model class of User.  I want to do all of the assignments / parsing inside of the user object.

I keep getting the message  - cannot invoke User with argument of type JSON

Any hints?

```
  let post = JSON(data)

                println("The post is: " + post.description)

                var user : User

                user(post[0])

                println(user.getName())



 import SwiftyJSON

class User {

var ObjectId = ""
  var FirstName = ""
  var LastName = ""
  var Organization = ""
  var CallSign = ""

init(sObjectId : String, sFirstName : String, sLastName : String,     sOrganization : String, sCallSign : String)
  {
ObjectId = sObjectId
FirstName = sFirstName
LastName = sLastName
Organization = sOrganization
CallSign = sCallSign


}

init(sUser : JSON) {

    self.ObjectId = sUser["_id"].string!
    self.FirstName = sUser["firstName"].string!
    self.LastName = sUser["lastName"].string!
    self.Organization = sUser["organization"].string!



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call the appropriate initializer directly

```
let post = JSON(data)
println("The post is: " + post.description)
var user = User(sUser: post[0])
```